# ayuda como Como recorrer este array JSON en PHP

Tags: php, json

hola como puedo hacer para obtener el name de cada uno de los que aparecen en este array de json con php. y gracias por la ayuda

```
"genres": [
    {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Aventura"
    },
    {
        "id": 878,
        "name": "Ciencia ficción"
    },
    {
        "id": 28,
        "name": "Acción"
    }
],
```

Comment: Me da la impresión de que el problema que tienes está en el paso de String a JSON. Si fuese eso prueba con json_decode()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto:

```
foreach($genres->data as $genre) {

  echo $genres->id. "\n";
  echo $genres->name;

}
```

La variable **$genres** es la que contiene tu **json**

Comment: gracias si me sirvió :)

Comment: A la orden, si puedes votame como positivo por favor

Answer (score 0):

Si lo quieres recorrer solo con php, lo podrías recorrer como un arreglo, y trabajarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
  $genres = [
              [
                "id" => 12,
                "name" => "Aventura"
              ],
              [
                "id" => 878,
                "name" => "Ciencia ficción"
              ],
              [
                "id" => 28,
                "name" => "Acción"
              ]
            ];

  foreach ($genres as $g) {
    echo $g['name'];
    echo '</br>';
  }

?>
```

Comment: gracias si me sirvió :)